# Whenever an author saves their post a \&quot; is added next to the double quotation marks

Tags: posts

As I mention on the title whenever an author saves their post a \" is added next to the double quotation marks

```
<img class="\&quot;alignnone\&quot;" src="\&quot;https://exmple.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/My-Post.jpg\&quot;" alt="\&quot;\&quot;" width="\&quot;1022\&quot;" height="\&quot;508\&quot;" />
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: If it didn't escape the quotes, you'd end up with invalid HTML. I don't see the code that's outputting that though? Eitherway the author shouldn't be adding quotes

Comment: Hello Tom, as you can see with the snippet above the author didn't add a quote but an image. This happens whenever an author saves their work. Whenever an admin or an editor adds an image and saves this does not happen.

Comment: I mean literal quote characters aka `"` it's the difference between `5` and `"5"`. Admins have the unfiltered HTML capability, and can enter anything. Note that you can't put quotes in an attribute, even if they're escaped without the slash, `width="&quot;5&quot;"` is still an invalid value. I also see there is still no code in your question to debug, it's not clear how the image tag is being output

Comment: Maybe I was unclear at first. The author was writing his post on wordpress using the basic wordpress system for doing so. No code was added to wordpress in order to affect the output that's why I didn't post any code for anyone to debug. He used the **Add Media** button to add the image. Then saved and the output was  the above.

Comment: and you're sure no quotes were added by the author? Can you include a screenshot of the UI so that it's clearer in your question what the input value were that generated that output? Can you confirm that this happens with a default theme and no plugins?

Comment: I will test it and come to you asap.